# Using .clear() or letting the GC take care of it

Tags: java, hashmap, garbage-collection

In a portion of my code, two LinkedHashMaps are created, like so:

```
Map<Byte, Integer> hash1 = new LinkedHashMap<Byte, Integer>();
Map<Byte, Integer> hash2 = new LinkedHashMap<Byte, Integer>();
```

After that, a for-loop is ran to add values into their respective HashMap, and then the HashMaps are ran through another loop used for packet creation. Would it be better to call .clear() after the second loop is called, or just let the garbage collector take care of it?

Comment: Do the hash maps go out of scope after the 2nd loop? Because as long as they stay in scope there is still a reference to their elements and the GC will not dispose of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't call clear(), the GC won't take care of it, because the objects will still be referenced by the hashmap until it goes out of scope.

If the hashmap is going out of scope anyway, you can let the GC handle it.  It likely won't make a measurable difference to clear it first.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the two HashMaps are created in a function, and don't get returned at any point. Their scope lays within that function itself.

Comment: @PuppyKevin, then clearing them or null-ing the references to them would be a complete waste of your time, and have no effect on performance whatsoever.

Comment: If that's the case, then as I suggested above, indeed there's probably not a lot of difference.  Theoretically (and I stress theoretically), you might make the mark phase of the GC process a bit simpler if there are no references left at all to the hashmap members (even though the hashmaps themselves are no longer referenced).  Realistically, you'll probably never notice the difference.  If you're very concerned about memory overhead, try reusing a byte buffer for each function rather than creating new objects each time.  This is probably premature optimization though.

Comment: In fact, clearing the hashmap just before it goes out of scope will degrade performance by exactly the miniscule amount of time to do the `clear()` since GC will collect all the objects involved without needind to erase the hashmap references.

Comment: Alright, thanks everyone. I had thought that using .clear() wouldn't help me gain in performance, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `clear()` on these maps is likely to be an expensive waste of time, from the perspective of garbage collection.

There are three cases to consider:

- If the variables containing the (only) HashMap references are about to go out of scope, calling `clear()` on them is a waste of time.  Even assigning `null` to the variables is a (miniscule) waste of time.

  The `HashMap` objects will be collected next time the GC is run on the heap that contains them.  Calling `clear()` won't make this happen faster, and won't reduce the work done by the GC.
- If the variables are not about to go out of scope, but you are not going to reuse the `HashMaps`, then assigning `null` to them *may* make the HashMaps eligible for GC a bit sooner, but the JVM *may* deal with this case anyway.  Calling `clear()` is a waste of time, as above.
- If the variables are not going out of scope, and you are going to reuse the `HashMaps`, then clearing them may be the right thing to do.  However the real purpose of calling `clear()` would be to get rid of old (and presumably unwanted) map entries that are liable to slow down hash table operations, and that could result in incorrect results.

(This is an elaboration of the comments on @squacknull's answer.)

---

To understand why calling `clear` doesn't help the GC, you need to understand how the HotSpot collectors work.  The HotSpot collectors are "copying" collectors that copy from a "from" space to a "to" space.  The work is done by recursively tracing the reachable objects in the "from" space and copying them to the "to" space.  Then, any remaining objects are checked to see if they need to be finalized, and the finalizable objects are recursively traced and copied to "to" space.  Finally, the "from" space is zeroed, and the GC is done.  (It is more complicated than that, when you consider generations, concurrent collectors and so on, but lets not go there ...)

Assuming that the HashMap is unreachable and not finalizable, then neither phases of marking it will find either it, its internal objects (i.e. the hash array or the chains) or the keys and values in the map ... assuming the latter are not reachable by some other route.  Thus, clearing the hash array (which is what `clear()` does) is just clearing elements of an object that wasn't going to be traced anyway.  It has no effect on what the GC has to do.