# How to handle out of memory exception while working with HashMap

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, garbage-collection, hashmap

I am using a HashMap which stores 1000 entries at a time. After processing the records I call clear() method and loads 1000 fresh entries for same HashMap reference. I have to do this same process for 2,000,0000 records. Buyt after processing only 750,000 its gives me Exception in thread "ThreadedStreamConsumer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

I have also tried WeekHashMap but it also didn't work out for me. What should be the effective method to handle this?

Comment: `2,000,0000 records` are stored in database?

Comment: See if it helps.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127682/java-memory-management-with-hashmap?rq=1

Comment: Either you're not really clearing the map, or you're holding onto the data elsewhere. Or maybe, given the "ThreadedStreamConsumer," you're spinning up too many threads and their total consumption exceeds what you have available. But without you showing actual code, it's impossible to say what the real problem might be.

Comment: You have to somehow eliminate *all* references to the objects which you want to "forget".  Eg, if you create a new HashMap for the new ones, you must null all references to the old HashMap (or overwrite them with references to the new one).  And any other array containing lists of the objects must be similarly disposed of.  Somewhere you're hanging on to lists of old objects.

Comment: are the records the same size. Is it possible that the error occur in a specific record which is causing the error? Have you noticed if it occurs in a specific record? Can you increase the available memory of your project?

Comment: You can try creating a new `HashMap` instead of calling `clear()`. If that doesn't help the root cause is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the memory leak isn't related to `HashMap`, but somewhere else.
You would find where the leak is by analyzing the heap dump.

In order to instruct JVM to produce the heap dump upon `OutOfMemoryError` add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` parameter to the `java` command line.

Once you have the heap dump, load it using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html) or any other profiler of your choice.
That will allow you to find what's the object holds references to the processed records and amend you program to prevent that.